# MVC htaccess rewrite code and force www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

Im creating small site with mvc architecture. anyone has a code that most suited to use in this type of programming?

I want force non-www to www on my url and append all arguments to $_GET variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be for you . Enter it in the file and go

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thankyou for the fast reply but the url doesnt redirect to www.

Comment: @MashiruAlexis - Sorry, I read your question too quickly , I edited the code

Comment: it works, my url is now parsing to www but where can i access the arguments in the url parameter ?

Comment: @MashiruAlexis - Where you Want in Your **PHP** files . If you have a **URL** of the type `www.example.com?test=stackoverflow` you can do `$_REQUEST["test"]`

Comment: you really helped a lot, can i pass this to index file ?

i wanted to look it like this
    from: www.example.com/index.php?url=user/login

    to this one: www.example.com/user/login

is that possible?

Comment: @MashiruAlexis - It can be done, but it's a different story, we will go off-topic. Better than open a separate discussion that is difficult to explain here in the comments without the use of an indented code.You can be considered my answer as correct, if you want.